# Automated testing of HLS video stream

Tags: automation, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am currently manually testing HLS streams on mobile devices. I want to create a tool that would help me automate all the test cases and extract the following information from the video stream:

1. Audio Video Sync.
2. Closed Captioning

I feel like I am shooting in the air over here. Any pointers would be really appreciated.